# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "public" in Error Message On PHP 8.1

Tags: php, function, syntax, token, public

The above error message is triggered, when running in PHP 8.1.

Haven't been able to spot anything obvious, as to where the code below needs to be changed to eliminate this error message.

```
 public function process_button()
{
    $sid = zen_session_name() . '=' . zen_session_id();
    $formEntries = $this->buildStandardTransactionDetails();
    $formEntries['SuccessURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
    $formEntries['FailureURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
    $processButtonString = SagepayUtil::processCryptEntries($formEntries);

    $crypt = SagepayUtil::encryptAndEncode($processButtonString, MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_PASSWORD);

    $transaction_type = strtoupper(MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_TXTYPE);
    $this->errorLog(array(
        array('title' => 'Transaction Type', 'content' => $transaction_type),
        array('title' => 'Submit Data', 'content' => $processButtonString)
    ));

    $process_button_string = zen_draw_hidden_field('VPSProtocol', self::SP_PROTOCOL_VERSION) .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('TxType', $transaction_type) .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('Vendor', MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_VENDOR_NAME) .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('ReferrerID', 'BB5F9F0D-8982-4203-AFD4-AF78017E4B92') .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('Crypt', $crypt);
    return $process_button_string;
}
```

The error points to the first line of code (as below):

```
 public function process_button()
```

Full php file:

```
<?php
/**
* sagepay form
*
* @package paymentMethod
* @copyright Copyright 2003-2017 Zen Cart Development Team
* @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
* @copyright Portions Copyright Nixak
* @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License 
V2.0
* @version $Id: Author: zcwilt  June 2017 New in v1.5.5 $
*/
require_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG . DIR_WS_MODULES . 
'payment/sagepay_zc/SagepayBasket.php');
require_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG . DIR_WS_MODULES . 
'payment/sagepay_zc/SagepayCustomer.php');
require_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG . DIR_WS_MODULES . 
'payment/sagepay_zc/SagepayUtil.php');
 require_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG . DIR_WS_MODULES . 
 'payment/sagepay_zc/sagepay_zc_payment.php');

/**
 * Class sagepay_form
*/
 class sagepay_zc_form extends sagepay_zc_payment
 {

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $sagepayResponse;

/**
 *
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->code = 'sagepay_zc_form';
    parent::__construct();
    $this->form_action_url = 
    'https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp';
    if (MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_TEST_STATUS == 'test') {
    $this->form_action_url = 
   'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp';
    }
    if ((extension_loaded('suhosin') || defined("SUHOSIN_PATCH"))  && 
    ini_get('suhosin.get.max_value_length') < 600) {
        $this->title .= '<span class="">' . TEXT_TITLE_SUHOSIN_ERROR . 
    '</span>';
        $this->description = '<span class="">' . 
    TEXT_DESCRIPTION_SUHOSIN_GET_LENGTH_ERROR . '</span><br><br>' . 
    $this->description;
    if ((extension_loaded('suhosin') || defined("SUHOSIN_PATCH"))  && 
    ini_get('suhosin.get.max_value_length') < 600) {
        $this->title .= '<span class="">' . TEXT_TITLE_SUHOSIN_ERROR . 
    '</span>';
        $this->description = '<span class="">' . 
    TEXT_DESCRIPTION_SUHOSIN_GET_LENGTH_ERROR . '</span><br><br>' . 
    $this->description;
        $this->enabled = false;
    }
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
   public function process_button()
    {
    $sid = zen_session_name() . '=' . zen_session_id();
    $formEntries = $this->buildStandardTransactionDetails();
    $formEntries['SuccessURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', 
    zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
    $formEntries['FailureURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', 
    zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
    $processButtonString = 
    SagepayUtil::processCryptEntries($formEntries);

    $crypt = SagepayUtil::encryptAndEncode($processButtonString, 
    MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_PASSWORD);

    $transaction_type = 
    strtoupper(MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_TXTYPE);
    $this->errorLog(array(
        array('title' => 'Transaction Type', 'content' => 
    $transaction_type),
        array('title' => 'Submit Data', 'content' => 
    $processButtonString)
    ));

    $process_button_string = zen_draw_hidden_field('VPSProtocol', 
    self::SP_PROTOCOL_VERSION) .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('TxType', $transaction_type) .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('Vendor', 
    MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_VENDOR_NAME) .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('ReferrerID', 'BB5F9F0D-8982-4203-AFD4- 
    AF78017E4B92') .
        zen_draw_hidden_field('Crypt', $crypt);
    return $process_button_string;
    }

   /**
   *
   */
   public function before_process()
    {
    global $messageStack;
    $sagepay_return_data = SagepayUtil::decodeAndDecrypt($_GET['crypt'], 
    MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_PASSWORD);
    $this->errorLog(array(
        array('title' => 'Response Data', 'content' => 
    $sagepay_return_data)
    ));
    $this->sagepayResponse = 
    SagepayUtil::getResponseTokens($sagepay_return_data);

    $status = $this->sagepayResponse['Status'];
    if (in_array($status, array('OK', 'REGISTERED', 'AUTHENTICATED'))) {
        return;
    }
    $error_message = $this->getResponseErrorMessage($this- 
    >sagepayResponse['Status']);
    $payment_error_return = 'ERROR ' . sprintf($error_message, $this- 
    >sagepayResponse['StatusDetail']);
    $this->errorLog(array(
        array('title' => 'Response Values', 'content' => implode("\n", 
    $this->sagepayResponse))
    ));
    $messageStack->add_session('checkout_payment', 
    $payment_error_return, 'error');
    zen_redirect(zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PAYMENT, '', 'SSL', 
    true, false));
    }

    /**
    * @param $zf_order_id
   */
    public function after_order_create($zf_order_id)
    {
    global $db;
    $transactionData = $this->sagepayResponse;
    $sagepayTransaction = array();
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'vpstxid', 'value' => 
    $transactionData['VPSTxId'], 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'zen_order_id', 'value' 
    => $zf_order_id, 'type' => 'integer');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'api_type', 'value' => 
    $this->code, 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'vendor_tx_code', 
    'value' => $transactionData['VendorTxCode'], 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'transaction_status', 
    'value' => $transactionData['Status'], 'type' => 'string');
     $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'status_detail', 
    'value' => issetorArray($transactionData, 'StatusDetail', ''), 
    'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'tx_auth_no', 'value' 
    => issetorArray($transactionData, 'TxAuthNo', ''), 'type' => 
    'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'avs_cv2', 'value' => 
    issetorArray($transactionData, 'AVSCV2', ''), 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'address_result', 
    'value' => issetorArray($transactionData, 'AddressResult', ''), 
    'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'postcode_result', 
   'value' => issetorArray($transactionData, 'PostCodeResult', ''), 
   'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'cv2_result', 'value' 
    => issetorArray($transactionData, 'CV2Result', ''), 'type' => 
    'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 
    'three_d_secure_status', 'value' => issetorArray($transactionData, 
    '3DSecureStatus', ''), 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'cavv_result', 'value' 
    => issetorArray($transactionData, 'CAVV', ''), 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'card_type', 'value' => 
    issetorArray($transactionData, 'CardType', ''), 'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'last_4_digits', 
    'value' => issetorArray($transactionData, 'Last4Digits', ''), 'type' 
    => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'address_status', 
   'value' => issetorArray($transactionData, 'AddressStatus', ''), 
   'type' => 'string');
    $sagepayTransaction[] = array('fieldName' => 'payer_status', 'value' 
    => issetorArray($transactionData, 'PayerStatus', ''), 'type' => 
    'string');
    $db->perform(TABLE_SAGEPAY_TRANSACTION, $sagepayTransaction);
    }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php    --- has some good observations on how to construct a public function.

Comment: Please share the full PHP file if possible.

Comment: Hi Koala. I've added the full PHP file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is not part of a class. So remove the `public` keyword to be just

```
function process_button()
```

#### Update

After you edited the question is clear, there is a syntax error. The closing brace `}` is missing at the end of the constructor.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->code = 'sagepay_zc_form';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->form_action_url =
            'https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp';
        if (MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_TEST_STATUS == 'test') {
            $this->form_action_url =
                'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp';
        }
        if ((extension_loaded('suhosin') || defined("SUHOSIN_PATCH"))  &&
            ini_get('suhosin.get.max_value_length') < 600) {
            $this->title .= '<span class="">' . TEXT_TITLE_SUHOSIN_ERROR .
                '</span>';
            $this->description = '<span class="">' .
                TEXT_DESCRIPTION_SUHOSIN_GET_LENGTH_ERROR . '</span><br><br>' .
                $this->description;
            if ((extension_loaded('suhosin') || defined("SUHOSIN_PATCH"))  &&
                ini_get('suhosin.get.max_value_length') < 600) {
                $this->title .= '<span class="">' . TEXT_TITLE_SUHOSIN_ERROR .
                    '</span>';
                $this->description = '<span class="">' .
                    TEXT_DESCRIPTION_SUHOSIN_GET_LENGTH_ERROR . '</span><br><br>' .
                    $this->description;
                $this->enabled = false;
            }
        }
    } // <-- This one is missing
```

So since it is a class method, re-add the `public` keyword back in.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Should have mentioned. That was the first thing that was tried before posting on this forum. Error message still persists by removing the public part of the function.

Comment: @user21167050 Please see my answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it! Although this has now generated a new error message in another php file.

Comment: Read carefully about the error message. It exactly said what the problem is. In this case, it said the public keyword was not expected. What is true, because it waited for a mssing closing brace.

Comment: Thanks Markus. I'm fairly new to php, so still learning, but appreciate all your help!

Comment: Another advice is using a smart IDE like PHPStorm. This will help you greatly detecting such errors.

Comment: Funny you should say that. Actually ran that through there using Rector for php (set at PHP 8.1). Rector did make some changes to some of the other files.

Comment: LOL. I think those changes were not smart enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the **`public`** keyword to a function in PHP and it is giving you an error, it is likely because you are not using it within a class.

So, here you are also doing the same you are adding public keyword to a function that is not inside any class.

So, the solution for this is to simply remove the **`public`** keyword from the front of function or to define the function inside some class as follows:

```
<?php

class Test{
    public function process_button()
    {
        $sid = zen_session_name() . '=' . zen_session_id();
        $formEntries = $this->buildStandardTransactionDetails();
        $formEntries['SuccessURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
        $formEntries['FailureURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
        $processButtonString = SagepayUtil::processCryptEntries($formEntries);

        $crypt = SagepayUtil::encryptAndEncode($processButtonString, MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_PASSWORD);

        $transaction_type = strtoupper(MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_TXTYPE);
        $this->errorLog(
            array(
                array('title' => 'Transaction Type', 'content' => $transaction_type),
                array('title' => 'Submit Data', 'content' => $processButtonString)
            )
        );

        $process_button_string = zen_draw_hidden_field('VPSProtocol', self::SP_PROTOCOL_VERSION) .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('TxType', $transaction_type) .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('Vendor', MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_VENDOR_NAME) .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('ReferrerID', 'BB5F9F0D-8982-4203-AFD4-AF78017E4B92') .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('Crypt', $crypt);
        return $process_button_string;
    }
}
?>
```

If you want dont want to define the function inside a class then try the following code:

```
<?php

     function process_button()
    {
        $sid = zen_session_name() . '=' . zen_session_id();
        $formEntries = $this->buildStandardTransactionDetails();
        $formEntries['SuccessURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
        $formEntries['FailureURL'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, $sid, 'SSL', false));
        $processButtonString = SagepayUtil::processCryptEntries($formEntries);

        $crypt = SagepayUtil::encryptAndEncode($processButtonString, MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_PASSWORD);

        $transaction_type = strtoupper(MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_TXTYPE);
        $this->errorLog(
            array(
                array('title' => 'Transaction Type', 'content' => $transaction_type),
                array('title' => 'Submit Data', 'content' => $processButtonString)
            )
        );

        $process_button_string = zen_draw_hidden_field('VPSProtocol', self::SP_PROTOCOL_VERSION) .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('TxType', $transaction_type) .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('Vendor', MODULE_PAYMENT_SAGEPAY_ZC_FORM_VENDOR_NAME) .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('ReferrerID', 'BB5F9F0D-8982-4203-AFD4-AF78017E4B92') .
            zen_draw_hidden_field('Crypt', $crypt);
        return $process_button_string;
    }

?>
```

Here, in the above code i just removed the access specifier `public`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `public` keyword. But to the code just before it.

The `__construct()` function misses the closing parentheses `}`. So anything immediately after that would be unexpected keyword. Just add one more `}` before the next function and things should be fixed.